# how to return a new instance in julia

Tags: struct, julia, instance

how can I return a new instance from a `struct` within a function in Julia?

```
function generateField(type, default, description, max, min)
 return Field{type}(default,description,min,max)
end
```

I have a struct called Field. I just used `Java` logic hier and it did not work for sure :)

```
    struct Field{T}
   type::T
   default::T
   description::String
   min::T
   max::T
  function Field{T}(description,min,max) where {T}
       new{T}(description, min, max)
  end 
end
```

Comment: You should post the struct definition for Field, the generateField call you tried, and the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `deepcopy(obj)` - it will make a copy of your struct object (assuming this is what you need):

```
julia> mutable struct Field2{T<:Real}
       a::T
       b::Vector{Float64}
       end

julia> x = Field2{Int}(5,[4.5])
Field2{Int64}(5, [4.5])

julia> y = deepcopy(x)
Field2{Int64}(5, [4.5])

julia> y == x
false
```

Note that `x` and `y` point to different variables and hence `x == y` yields false. To compare by value one would need to iterate over all struct fields.

For this `struct` a function generating it could be defined as :

```
function f(a::T, b::Vector{Float64}) where T <: Real
   return Field2{T}(a,b)
end
```

And used as:

```
julia> f(1//2, [3.5])
Field2{Rational{Int64}}(1//2, [3.5])
```

Finally, note that the function generating an object can have the same name as its type - in that case you are generating new constructor:

```
julia> Field2(a::T) where T<:Real = Field2{T}(a,Int[]);

julia> Field2(2)
Field2{Int64}(2, Float64[])
```

Comment: The OP is a bit unclear; I'm not sure whether they're really looking for something like [ConstructionBase](https://github.com/JuliaObjects/ConstructionBase.jl)...?

Comment: I am trying to return an instance of a Struct by calling a function  
 `function generateField(type, default, description, max, min)

     instance=Field{type}(default,description,min,max)
     return instance
end`                                                                                                       
 but when a call the function I got **LoadError: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Field{:Int16}(::Symbol, ::String, ::Expr, ::Int64)**

Comment: In that case edit your question to show ho your struct looks like.